# How to convert jupyter notebook (ipython) to slideshow NOT using command line

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am new with `Jupyter`, and I use Amazon SageMaker so that everything is cloud based and not local.  I cannot use any resources locally, nor can I install `Jupyter` on this local computer that I want to do this on, so I cannot use the command line to put :

```
jupyter nbconvert Jupyter\ Slides.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

So, I am struggling to find a way to convert my notebook to a slideshow NOT using command line. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below steps to convert your notebook to slides on AWS Sagemaker (tried on sagemaker notebook instance) without installing any extensions.

**Step 1:** Follow this [article](https://medium.com/@mjspeck/presenting-code-using-jupyter-notebook-slides-a8a3c3b59d67) to chose which cells in your notebook can be presented or skipped.
  - Go to View → Cell Toolbar → Slideshow
  - A light gray bar will appear above each cell with a scroll down window on the top right
  - Select type of slide each cell should be - regular slide, sub-slide, skip, notes

**Step 2:** Go to Sagemaker notebook home page and open terminal

[image]

**Step 3:** Change directory in the instance where your notebook exists

[image]

**Step 4:** Clone `reveal.js` in the directory where notebook exists from [github](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js). `reveal.js` is used for rendering HTML file as presentation.

[image]

**Step 5:** Run the below command (same as in your question) to convert the notebook to slides without serving them (since there is no browser on the Sagemaker instance). This will just convert notebook to slides html.

```
jupyter nbconvert Image-classification-fulltraining.ipynb --to slides
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook Image-classification-fulltraining.ipynb to slides
[NbConvertApp] Writing 346423 bytes to Image-classification-fulltraining.slides.html
```

**Step 6:** Now open the html file from Sagemaker notebook file browser

[image]

Now you can see the notebook rendered as slides based on how setup each cell in your notebook in Step 1

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you rajesh.  I am new to the SageMaker and didn't think of the terminal!  This is excellent!!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by [clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for using Amazon SageMaker.

You can run any command from within Jupyter cell using `!` before the command or open a new terminal from "New" at upper right side.

If you want to use nbconvert you can run the jupyter nbconvert command using above mentioned approach or as gboffi mentioned, you can use [RISE](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE) by Damian Avila to use your Jupyter Notebooks as slideshow.

In SageMaker Notebook Instances you can install this or any extension directly in Notebook Instance or using [Lifecycle Configuration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/customize-your-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instances-with-lifecycle-configurations-and-the-option-to-disable-internet-access/).

**Installation directly in Notebook Instance:**
To install directly in Notebook Instance, open the Notebook Instance then open a terminal. To install the extension you can run `conda install -c damianavila82 rise`. Please note that the extension will go away when you restart the Notebook Instance. To keep the extension across restarts, I would recommend using Lifecycle Configuration.

**Installation using Lifecycle Configuration:**
In SageMaker console create a Lifecycle Configuration with following content in "Start Notebook" section and Create a Notebook Instance with this Lifecycle Configuration. This way anytime you restart the Notebook Instance you will get this extension already installed on it.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate JupyterSystemEnv
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/conda install -y -c conda-forge rise
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me if you can or if you can not install notebook's extensions in your remote service.

If you can, [RISE](https://github.com/damianavila/RISE), by Damian Avila, is what you want.  Quoting from its home page:

> RISE allows you to instantly turn your Jupyter Notebooks into a slideshow. No out-of-band conversion is needed, switch from jupyter notebook to a live reveal.js-based slideshow in a single keystroke, and back.

I'd like to add that it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon SageMaker for new users of revealjs. [SageMaker metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/985o1.png)
Edit the meta data to adjust slide show parameters such as background images